# Windows 10 IoT user files removed after upgrading via AppManager

Tags: settings, application-settings, windowsiot

I'm facing an issue with how Windows 10 IoT and user files works. Whenever I try to update the application via AppManager, which seems to be the only current way to update/upgrade an app, the user files are removed.

Does anyone know a work around for this issue? Writing files to any other location seems to be disabled, and I'm faced with Unauthorized exception.

To get the LocalFolder in appData for the installed package Ive used the following:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path
```

Using version 10.0.10586.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to my problem, so instead I had to do a workaround. The workaround is to write the settings files, that I want to keep after upgrading/updating the software, to the Videos/Pictures folder of the DefaultUser.

The appmanifest has to be updated with the correct permission, so remember to add Videos or Pictures access as allowed by the app.

Hopefully this can help someone else if they have the same problem as me!